# How to generate a bar chart from a single row across multiple variables in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, rows

I have a large number of variables (3000 variables) and I want to generate a bar chart for each row separately (140 rows). I know I can't write all variables in the script.

```
barchart(V1+V2+V3+...+V3000~ var,
         data=my_data,
         auto.key=list(space='right')
         )
```

Comment: You seem to have confused [bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart) with [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) which actually are different things. I assumed you meant bar chart, just edit the edit if I was wrong and see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591998/6574038) below for both cases.

Comment: Hi, no I actually meant histogram (but I figured out how to transpose the data frame - it was easier to calculate histograms that way) sorry i'm still a beginner in r. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Use your desired plotting function in a `for` loop over the rows of your data.

```
## bar chart version
op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
  barplot(unlist(dat[i, ]), main=i)
}
par(op)
```

[image]

```
## histogram version
op <- par(mfrow=c(3, 2))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
  hist(unlist(dat[i, ]), main=i)
}
par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(6, rpois(6, 3)))
```